# Could jQuery use getters and setters?

Tags: jquery, getter-setter

I'm learning how to define getters and setters in JavaScript:

```
myObject = {}
myParameters = {}
myParameters.get = function() { 
    return this.value 
}

myParameters.set = function(myArgument) { 
    this.value = myArgument
}
Object.defineProperty(myObject, 'myProperty', myParameters)
myObject.myProperty = 3.14
console.log(myObject.myProperty)
```

Q: Could jQuery use getters instead of: `$('#myId').val()` or `$('#myId').text()`?

Could jQuery use setters instead of `$('#myId').val(x)` or `$('#myId').text(x)`?

Comment: Also, note that getters/setters are not strictly superior to function calls; especially since jquery's core design involves *chaining* functions.

Comment: @tcooc: That is a **very** good point.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it certainly could. But it was originally created long before JavaScript had getters and setters. jQuery was created in January 2006. Standardized JavaScript (properly, "ECMAScript") didn't officially get getters and setters until the ECMAScript 5th edition specification in December 2009 (although Mozilla's JavaScript had them prior to that), and it was **years** before browsers in the wild could be relied upon to have them (indeed, IE8 still has close to [3% of the worldwide market share](http://marketshare.hitslink.com/browser-market-share.aspx?qprid=2&qpcustomd=0), and it doesn't support them except — bizarrely — on DOM elements).

And there's [tcooc's very good point](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40363154/could-jquery-use-getters-and-setters/40363242#comment67979597_40363154) that using setters would mean you couldn't do call chaining like `$("#foo").text("updated").addClass("highlight");`, which is a significant feature of jQuery's API (not saying it's either good or bad, just that it's significant).